# Library Not found Mac OS with prescribed environment, IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Library is not being recognized.

I have downloaded the appropriate environment and tested it by completed steps 1-5 seen [here](https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/mac/).

The libraries should be included (described in [Using the textbook libraries](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/)).

I expected the code snippet to take input from the terminal, assign it's value to a variable and then print the value onto the Command-line. I used a snippet of code directly from the [Booksite](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html) to do this. It won't work:

[image]

[image]

I think the issue is coming from the instructions seen in bullet point 3 under [Using the textbook libraries](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/) (seen in picture that follows), but I don't know what to do with this information or what it means for me. Please, help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case any newbie's face the same issue. I used a different command and the program was able to run from the terminal:

```
~/Desktop/hello> javac-algs4 FileName.java
~/Desktop/hello> java-algs4 FileName
```